# Can I stop append to write file

Tags: java

This is a list of my output for a program I test.

```
 1. 031.bmp = M.bmp : 4142.0
 2. 036.bmp = M.bmp : 3946.0
 3. 038.bmp = B.bmp : 5420.0
 4. 042.bmp = 4.bmp : 3646.0
 5. 044.bmp = B.bmp : 3034.0
 6. 045.bmp = B.bmp : 3373.0
 7. 047.bmp = B.bmp : 3801.0
 8. 1044.bmp = 9.bmp : 3744.0
 9. 312.bmp = 1.bmp : 4555.0
 10. 314.bmp = M.bmp : 3196.0
 11. 316.bmp = F.bmp : 2904.0
 12. 319.bmp = T.bmp : 2453.0
 13. 320.bmp = B.bmp : 5013.0
 14. 321.bmp = B.bmp : 4435.0
 15. 512.bmp = B.bmp : 5085.0
 16. 514.bmp = 1.bmp : 3240.0
 17. 516.bmp = B.bmp : 5171.0
 18. 58.bmp = 1.bmp : 4214.0
 19. 59.bmp = B.bmp : 5119.0
 20. 617.bmp = B.bmp : 5020.0
```

And this is the part code to write to file

```
for (int o = 0; o < listOfChaFFiles.length; o++) {
    if (o < 1) {
        System.out.println(listOfTmpFFiles[tf].getName() + " = " + listOfChaFFiles[o].getName() + " : " + distances[o]);

        for(int gm=0; gm<listOfSrcFFiles.length; gm++){

            File imgFile = listOfSrcFFiles[gm];
            String fileName = imgFile.getName();
            String record = listOfChaFFiles[o].getName().substring(0, 1);

            //String record = listOfChaFFiles[o].getName().substring(0, 1) + " Difference to = " +distances[o]
            File file =new File("Result_"+fileName+".txt");

            //if file doesnt exists, then create it
            if(!file.exists()){
                file.createNewFile();
                }

            //true = append file
            FileWriter fileWritter = new FileWriter(file.getName(),true);
            BufferedWriter bufferWritter = new BufferedWriter(fileWritter);
            bufferWritter.write(record+ " ");
            bufferWritter.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

For now I create a multiple text file that will store these output in it and seperated by the name of the file. Supposed 031.bmp-047.bmp is from one file and 312.bmp - 321.bmp from another file and 512.bmp - 59.bmp is from another file.

Right now when I create the text file and append write to it all the output will be write altogether and not seperated. Can I do seperate them like stop it any condition or else. I want to write like 031.bmp - 321.bmp in one text file and write the next into another file. I am not that good in java so I dont know how to do it or if its possible. Sorry and thank you

Comment: The `file.exists()/file.createNewFile()` part is completely redundant. Remove it. The file system already has to do all that when you call `new FileOutputStream()`. You're tripling the overhead of creating the file. If you don't want to append to the file, pass `false` instead of `true` to the constructor, or omit the parameter altogether. This is all documented.

Comment: Err, in the Javadoc for `FileWriter`?

Comment: I mean how do I write to return false to stop it.

Comment: Please read what I wrote again. I didn't say anything about returning false. I said to *pass* `false` as a parameter instead of `true`. If you need help with that, you will just have to find it elsewhere. It is all too trivial for words.